# Google Cloud pricing details programmatically for a specific instance type

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to get price for Google Compute programmatically by using following API

```
https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus
```

How can I look for a specific instance from API JSON response. For example "n1-custom-2-3840", I would like to look price for this specific instance but I cannot find this instance in API response. I tried to filter API response.

[Google Cloud calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator), recommends to use same API as above to pull prices but I cannot find instance types in API response.

May be some one can help.

Comment: Can you update your question with some examples of what have you tried ? Any API requests & responses will be helpful.

Comment: You will have to run a regex on the "description" field in the response to match the "n1" instance type. They don't have an "instanceType" field, sadly.